# Access slickgrid object by selector

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

How to access slickgrid object by selector after it has be initalized for example throught selector #myGrid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// init & store
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
$("#myGrid").data("gridInstance", grid);

// access later on
$("#myGrid").data("gridInstance").resizeCanvas();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish clearly between the JQuery object and the javascript grid object.

Your HTML markup should look look something like this:

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px"></div>
```

and your sctipt will look something like this.

```
var grid;
var columns = [ {... column stuff
var options = { ... grid options
var data = [ ... data for the grid

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

The JQuery selector `$("#myGrid")` will return a JQuery object wrapping the DOM element. Basically, this is giving you a reference to the `<div>` object on your page. It is just like any other element on your HTML page and has no functionality specific to the grid. It is a div, just like any other.

The `grid` variable in the JavaScript saves a reference to the newly created object (of type Slick.Grid). This is a custom object defined in the SlickGrid library which brings all the properties and methods needed to manipulate the grid. So for example if you want to call the `resizeCanvas()` method, you need to call this via the grid object, not the div element.

```
grid.resizeCanvas();
```